# Android Frame animation does not proceed more than one image

Tags: animationdrawable

I have created a folder called anim inside res folder. I have put 9 consequtive images in a folder called drawable inside res folder. Now I have created this:

public class AndroidAnimationActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about_screen);
    ImageView myAnimation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myanimation);
    final AnimationDrawable myAnimationDrawable= (AnimationDrawable)myAnimation.getDrawable();
    myAnimation.post(new Runnable(){  
        public void run() {   
            myAnimationDrawable.start();  
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you see I am trying to display this animation on a page called about_screen. It only shows the first frame and the rest of the frames are not shown (as animation). I have seen several people having similar problem like me but not exactly the same. I hope someone can help me with this. Please be specific. I am a new android learner. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced this problem, and the solution is simple.
The problem is, you are calling `myAnimationDrawable.start()` inside the `onCreate()` function.

You have two possible alternatives...

First one, make the animation interactive, so that you can call `myAnimationDrawable.start()`
inside some `onClick()` function.

Second option is to call `myAnimationDrawable.start()` inside `View.OnFocusChangeListener()`. In this case you don't have to make it interactive.

Comment: This is nice, in my case i moved the code from onCreate to onResume and it works right